# Testing for Raised Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I have this code:

```
begin
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    puts 'ERROR MUST HAVE BEEN RAISED IF I APPEAR'
    render action: :new, status: 404
end
```

and it's tested here:

```
let(:invalid_request){ get :show, id: Location.count + 1 }
describe 'runtime' do
    before { invalid_request }

    it 'should raise error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' do
        expect { invalid_request }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
end
```

and yet when I run this expectation, I get this paradoxical output:

```
      runtime
ERROR MUST HAVE BEEN RAISED IF I APPEAR
        should raise error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) LocationsController#show when location doesn't exist runtime should raise error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     Failure/Error: expect { invalid_request }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
       expected ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/controllers/locations_controller_spec.rb:45:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**So why is this?** Rails raises the error automatically, so even though I'm not raising it manually, it's still being raised and should be testable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesnt raise the error:

- it is raised
- but it is rescued

In the end, no error.

You should test that you get a 404.

Btw, `render new` with 404 feels wrong, you'd rather redirect.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now :) So why write a spec for raised errors? Surely you never ever want the error to appear under any context?

Comment: `expect(response.status).to eq 404`

Comment: there are tons of reasons you'd want an AR not found error to bubble. Rails will handle it as a 404 anyway, but it should be an exceptional thing to have a reference to a resource that doesn't exist. There are hooks to provide custom actions to 404s but i agree it seems wrong to render new and/or to rescue it.

Comment: @Starkers doesnt it anwer?